# IE won't recognize a no-repeat?

Tags: css, internet-explorer, fault

Well, [I have a website](http://pigymunk.co.uk) and the front page has this image repeated all the way down. While on Chrome, is only repeats once, just like I want it to.

```
body {
    color: #999999;
    background-color: #490000;
    background:url('http://pigymunk.co.uk/bgasdf2.png') fixed, url('http://pigymunk.co.uk/bgasdf.png') fixed;
    background-repeat: no-repeat, repeat;
    background-position: left top, left top;
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have

```
background-repeat: no-repeat, repeat;
```

You can only specify either `no-repeat` *or* `repeat` - not both, e.g.

```
background-repeat: no-repeat;
```

Chrome supports CSS3 syntax allowing both but many browsers such as IE consider this invalid as it doesn't support it. (Remember CSS2 is standard, CSS3 is only partially supported)

**Updated:**
To create a layerd background you need to use *layers* surprise surprise :).

```
body {
    color: #999999;
    background-color: #490000;
    background: url('http://pigymunk.co.uk/bgasdf.png');
    background-repeat: repeat;
    background-position: left top;
}

#logo {
    height: 200px;
    width: 220px;
    background: url('http://pigymunk.co.uk/bgasdf2.png') no-repeat top left;
    position: absolute;
    top: 0px; left: 0px;
}
```

HTML:

```
<body>
<div id="logo"></div>
...
```

or better yet, don't use a background image for your logo as it won't appear when background images are turned off, e.g. for printing. Crop the image to the correct size for the logo and put it in the html

```
<body>
<div id="logo"><img src="http://pigymunk.co.uk/bgasdf2.png" alt="Piggymunk logo" /></div>

...
```

jsfiddle example: http://jsfiddle.net/ytL2w/

Comment: But it works fine in Chrome, and when I go to the blog (on IE) it works as it should.

Comment: But if I do this, it just has one, (no-repeat) I need to have a repeat and then a no-repeat.

Comment: @user1408280 CSS doesn't allow for that syntax so it doesn't really matter what you *want* - you can only do what CSS lets you :) But I don't understand hat do you mean "a repeat and a no-repeat"?

Comment: ok, thanks but is there any way I can get my wanted layered backgrounds?

Comment: You don't need to repeat the background with the face. Create a separate div as part of your content and put it in there

Comment: OK, for my site, http://pigymunk.co.uk, I need to have a plain, repeated background, and then another image on top that is not repeated. is this possible?

Comment: @pigymunk as I said, create a separate div and put the 2nd image there. I've edited my answer with an example. I also recommend you do learn a bit more about HTML & CSS because you will keep running into errors when you don't understand the concept of elements. You are trying to use CSS3 syntax in a HTML4 page.

Comment: @pigymunk it works fine, you may have a syntax error? See the jsfiddle link I added to my answer

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
body {
color: #999999;
background-color: #490000;
background-image:url('http://pigymunk.co.uk/bgasdf2.png');
background-position: fixed;
background-repeat: no-repeat;
}
```

Comment: have a look at the site, it's 2 backgrounds layered on top of eachother

Answer (score 0):

This works fine in IE9 for me:

```
body {
    color: #999999;
    background-color: #490000;
    background: url('http://pigymunk.co.uk/bgasdf2.png') no-repeat fixed left top, 
    url('http://pigymunk.co.uk/bgasdf.png') repeat fixed left top;
}
```

Comment: Using the separate CSS attributes isn't a problem so both should work, its the fact that the OP's syntax is invalid.

Comment: yes, but I need the second background bgasdf.png to be underneath that one and repeated, but thanks for your help

Comment: The first one listed is the one on top. So you have to put last the one you want underneath.

Comment: I read both the question and the comment again - isn't this http://dabblet.com/gist/2764131 what you wanted? The background image http://pigymunk.co.uk/bgasdf.png is underneath and repeated and http://pigymunk.co.uk/bgasdf2.png is on top, not repeated.

Comment: Remember that this is CSS3 syntax and isn't fully supported by all browsers - as @pigymunk has discovered. (It works in IE9 because it does support it but previous versions of IE dont)

Comment: When there are just two images, the one above being in the top left corner there is the AlphaImageLoader filter option for IE6-8.

Comment: You could do that, but theres no need. Its much cleaner, simpler and all-browser-compatible to just use a div for the 2nd image as its only a single image that doesn't need any special treatment.